# copy constructor for two dimensional vector

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I want to write a copy constructor for two dimensional vector

relevant code:

```
MyMatrix :: MyMatrix(const MyMatrix & mat)       // Copy Constructor
{
    m_m = mat.m_m;
    m_n = mat.m_n;
    vector < vector <int> > m_matrix(m_n, std::vector<int>(m_m,0));

    for( int i=0;i<m_n ; i++)
    {
        for( int j=0; j<m_m ;j++)
        {
            m_matrix[i][j] = mat.m_matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work and I don't find the error. What's wrong in this code?

```
class MyMatrix
{
 public:            // Methods

    MyMatrix();
    MyMatrix(int n, int m);
    MyMatrix(int n, int m, std:: vector <std:: vector <int> > matrix );
    MyMatrix(const MyMatrix & mat) ;
    ~MyMatrix();        

  private:          // Attributes

    int m_n;
    int m_m;

    std:: vector <std:: vector <int> > m_matrix;

};
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" look like?  Only <int> in your matricies?  I would guess <double> would come in handy.  I'll also guess that allocating a vector of vectors is not sufficient.  You have to loop over each row and allocate individual row vectors before you assign values.

Comment: You don't need to write  a copy constructor. The compiler will make one for you that does the right thing. Without bugs.

Comment: What's wrong with the default copy constructor?

Comment: it compiles but when I run the code, the program is blocked

Comment: And `vector < vector <int> > m_matrix(m_n, std::vector<int>(m_m,0));` regardless is a local variable in your constructor, Your member is never touched after default initialization.

Comment: @juanchopanza why I don't need to write a copy constructor?

Comment: Because wit this class you don't need to. You get one for free.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm sorry I don't understand ... why with this class?

Comment: @Laura because the members in this class are sufficient that default copy construction is perfectly valid. The compiler-generated default copy-ctor will properly copy those members for you if you *don't* try to overload the copy-ctor in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyMatrix :: MyMatrix(const MyMatrix & mat):m_m(mat.m_m), m_n(mat.m_n), m_matrix(mat.m_matrix)
{
}
```

You were creating a local variable with the same name as the member variable. trust the vector to copy itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it doesn't compile It doesn't receive the m_matrix(m_n, std::vector<int>(m_m,0));

Comment: try the version where the vector is copied in the initialiser list.

Comment: It works!! what was wrong with the precedent code? can you explain me please? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Laura but this is not a good solution. The right solution is not to write the copy constructor in the first place.

Comment: I think you had got your indexes mixed up.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I agree. There is no point in writing a CC on this class but sometimes it is a useful exercise to understand how to hand code.

Comment: But you are giving a beginner the wrong solution without explaining it.

Comment: If I gave the right solution at the start, it was not possible to point out other mistakes that can be repeated. Redeclaring the member variable as a local variable is a classic.

Comment: Because it is impossible to explain things correctly? Do you have a word limit or something?

Comment: Nope, its 2 AM in this part of the world :)

Answer (score 4):

Your trouble is in this line:

```
vector < vector <int> > m_matrix(m_n, std::vector<int>(m_m,0));
```

It's not doing what you think it's doing. You think you're initializing your member variable, but instead you're creating a local variable with the same name.

You should use an initializer list to initialize your member variables:

```
MyMatrix :: MyMatrix(const MyMatrix & mat)       // Copy Constructor
   : m_m(mat.m_m)
   , m_n(mat.m_n)
   , m_matrix(m_n, std::vector<int>(m_m,0))
{
 //...
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with your code is that you are declaring a local variable named `m_matrix` that shadows the data member `m_matrix`. You need to use the data member (but before you do so, you need resize it).

An even better approach is to use an initializer list.

```
MyMatrix::MyMatrix(const MyMatrix & mat)
:
    m_m(mat.m_m),
    m_n(mat.m_n),
    m_matrix(mat.m_matrix)
{}
```

With C++11, you have an even better option than the above. Just use the implicitly defined copy constructor. You can make this explicit in your class definition via the following.

```
class MyMatrix
{
...
public:
    ...
    MyMatrix (const MyMatrix & mat) = default;
...
};
```

There's another option that works in both C++03 and C++11: Don't write anything. Don't declare anything that qualifies as a copy constructor and you'll get an implicitly declared copy constructor. This implicitly declared copy constructor is implicitly defined if it is ever used, and in this case, there's not one thing wrong with that implicitly-declared / implicitly-defined copy constructor.

Comment: Without C++11 you have an even better solution too: don't write anything.

Comment: Omitting the decl entirely will provide default copy construction correctly and not pin you to C++11 (but the idea is correct regardless).

Comment: @juanchopanza - Agreed. That's what I wanted to write, but I had to take a few minutes to check the standard to ensure that that was indeed correct.